# The bwshare module and PHP scraping

Tags: php, screen-scraping, file-get-contents

I wrote a script downloading a list of pages from a website. From time to time I receive the following error (the number of seconds is variable):

> The bwshare module will refuse your requests for the next 7 seconds.
>   You have downloaded data too rapidly.

I found when using sleep(2) in the loop, it works much better, however the time delay is too expensive.
What's the best way how to deal with this module? Should I scrape it without any delay and if the response will be similar to the above message simply use sleep for the requested number of seconds?

Comment: Yes you need to set sleep to 7 seconds, or use many computers (with several IP) for grabbing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how many pages you can get before the error message.

Try and measure how many pages in average you can get.

**4 pages before the bwshare message is the minimum.**

If you are getting the error message *before* reaching 4 page downloads, then il would be  *faster* to sleep(2) after each download.

Comment: It's usually around 10-15 pages

Comment: Then, as I said, just sleep(7) when you get the bwshare error message. You will get more performance. Otherwise, getting 30 pages will cost you 1 minutes, instead of just 14 secs !

Comment: I'm also thinking of trying to log in using cURL because it might prevent this to happen.

Comment: I don't think so because bwshare rules are not aware of any session data, only pure Apache requests. Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

try this way... it might help u.

```
  $requestTime = 0.1; // s/connection

    foreach(/* blah */) {
        $start = microtime(true);
        // Do your stuff to here.. get_file_content($url) and other processing .........

        if($timeTaken = microtime(true)-$start < $requestTime) {
            usleep(($requestTime-$timeTaken)*1000000);
        }
    }
```

if your problem is solved then try to post your answer so that other people may also be benefited

Comment: we would like to know how did you overcome on the performance problem.... and what value did you find efficient to use in sleep(n)?

Comment: Because speed was necessary in the project, I decided to abandon that and use whole different way.